# When I execute Analogjs project "npm run dev", unable to solve this error. Anyone can guide me ? Is there any version related issue

Tags: vite, analogjs

I am trying to create an basic analogjs project I followed some command.
first I hit this command every thing is fine

1. npm create analog@latest

then I install node module in the project directory. still all good

2. npm i

but when I execute the project I am facing this error that you can see the image given below.

[image: click here to view the error screenshot]

or

The server endpoints are accessible under the "/api" path.
➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
➜  Network: use --host to expose

> 4:43:26 pm [vite] Error when evaluating SSR module
> /node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs: failed to import "rxjs"
> |- TypeError: Method Promise.prototype.then called on incompatible
> receiver [object Object]
> at ZoneAwarePromise.then ()
> at node:internal/per_context/primordials:440:35
> at new Promise ()
> at new SafePromise (node:internal/per_context/primordials:408:29)
> at node:internal/per_context/primordials:440:9
> at Array.map ()
> at arrayToSafePromiseIterable (node:internal/per_context/primordials:437:5)
> at node:internal/per_context/primordials:453:21
> at new Promise ()
> at primordials.SafePromiseAll (node:internal/per_context/primordials:452:3)
>
> 4:43:26 pm [vite] Error when evaluating SSR module
> ~analog/entry-server: failed to import
> "/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs" |- TypeError: Method
> Promise.prototype.then called on incompatible receiver [object Object]
> at ZoneAwarePromise.then ()
> at node:internal/per_context/primordials:440:35
> at new Promise ()
> at new SafePromise (node:internal/per_context/primordials:408:29)
> at node:internal/per_context/primordials:440:9
> at Array.map ()
> at arrayToSafePromiseIterable (node:internal/per_context/primordials:437:5)
> at node:internal/per_context/primordials:453:21
> at new Promise ()
> at primordials.SafePromiseAll (node:internal/per_context/primordials:452:3)

Comment: Please paste the error message as text.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe I added and added the respective screenshot also. Thanks you helping  me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should upgrade to node v18, just check with 18.18.0 and run without problem.